# How to calculate percentages, based on aspirasi_id

Tags: mysql, count, percentage

```
Select aspirasi_id
     , aspirasi_option_id
     , (Count(aspirasi_option_id)* 100 / 
           (Select Count(*) 
              From aspirasi_choices)
       ) as total 
  From aspirasi_choices  
 GROUP 
    BY aspirasi_option_id
```

output

[wrong value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyQl1.png)

How can I make per card, his total each not in join.

example 
[true value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeEFZ.png)

thanks before

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVT8c.png)

```html
my expectations
aspirasi_id     | aspirasi_option_id | total 
---------+----------+-------
 52             | 6        |  100.00% 
 53             | 5        |  50.00% 
 53             | 4        |  50.00% 
 
Reality 
aspirasi_id     | aspirasi_option_id | total 
---------+----------+-------
 52             | 6        |  33.33% 
 53             | 5        |  33.33% 
 53             | 4        |  33.33%
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need percentage to be divide per `aspirasi_id`, Add a where clause in your sub query like `WHERE aspirasi_id = a.aspirasi_id`

```
SELECT 
  a.aspirasi_id,
  a.aspirasi_option_id,
  (
    COUNT(aspirasi_option_id) * 100 / 
    (SELECT 
      COUNT(*) 
    FROM
      aspirasi_choices 
    WHERE aspirasi_id = a.aspirasi_id)
  ) AS total 
FROM
  aspirasi_choices a 
GROUP BY a.aspirasi_id,
  a.aspirasi_option_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d5bc7/3)

Or by using join you can rewrite above as

```
SELECT 
  a.aspirasi_id,
  a.aspirasi_option_id,
  COUNT(aspirasi_option_id) * 100 / b.inner_total AS total 
FROM
  aspirasi_choices a 
  JOIN (SELECT 
      aspirasi_id,
      COUNT(*) AS inner_total 
    FROM
      aspirasi_choices 
    GROUP BY aspirasi_id) b USING (aspirasi_id) 
GROUP BY a.aspirasi_id,
  a.aspirasi_option_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d5bc7/8)